# Before how many days or hours can I undelete a deleted question?

Tags: support

Before how many days or hours can I undelete a deleted question?

Do high rated users have any more benefits like archiving or something?

Comment: Not sure I understand either of your questions. Do you wonder if deleted posts are permanently deleted after some time? What do you mean by archiving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the privilege to undelete a question, as far as I know it can be done instantly you don't have to wait at all. (That's not the case when deleting, but this is different matter)

One exception though - ordinary user can't vote to undelete a question that was deleted by a moderator. This is fairly recent change made to prevent "delete wars".

There is not such thing as "archive", at least not directly.. however users with 10,000 reputation and more can see deleted posts, so here on Meta you can find discussions which list deleted questions that such high rep members can still see.